# Keyboard Layout in Windows 7 with VMware Fusion 5

Tags: windows, vmware, keyboard

I'm using my MacBook Pro for programming. I have a virtual Windows 7 machine running with VMware Fusion. When I switch from OS X to Windows 7, my keyboard layout changes. It's really annoying because I type lots of braces and parentheses.

I have been searching for hours and didn't find a solution to make my Mac keyboard work the same way in Windows. I've tried installing Bootcamp driver, Windows Keyboard Layout Creator, etc.

How do I get these keyboard layouts to sync up?

Comment: What is your normal keyboard layout -- US or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You don't give a lot of information about where you are based so I am making some references based on experience outside the US.

When setting up a machine here in South Africa, the system (even preconfigured ones) come with an additional keyboard layout (in our case US-International). We use US keyboard layout here. That layout causes the ' to require a double tap on the keyboard before it processes it. If we remove it so that it only has one layout and restart the machine the behaves correctly.

Check that you have the correct keyboard installed in Windows as VMWare tends to make some assumptions during VM creation.